# Qt5: How do I make the window scroll instead of expand as rows are added to QFormLayout? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, scroll, qt5, pyqt5

I have a window set up like this:

```
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
groupBox = QGroupBox()
formLayout = QFormLayout()
groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)
vbox.addWidget(groupBox)
```

I also have two buttons that add rows and remove rows from formLayout.

When I add too many rows such that they cannot fit in the defined window, the window expands vertically. When rows are deleted, the window remains at the expanded size.

I instead want to have the area scroll such that the new rows are only visible within the defined window size, and such that the window does not expand unless the user expands it manually. How can I add a scrolling feature to this and prevent the window from expanding?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. You can use QScrollArea(), as below:

```
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
groupBox = QGroupBox()
formLayout = QFormLayout()
groupBox.setLayout(formLayout)
scroll_area = QScrollArea()
scroll_area.setWidgetResizeable(True)
scroll_area.setWidget(groupBox)
vbox.addWidget(scroll_area)
```

This creates a window that doesn't change its size, but rather automatically adds a scroll bar when more rows are added to formLayout.